# C# Unity3D FPS apply damage to an enemy (Weapon bullet)

Tags: c#, unity, first-person-shooter

I am kindly new to Unity3d and c# and I don't understand how I could let a bullet deal damage to an other object. I've seen a lot of JS tutorials but no for C#. I've tried to use them, but it wont work. My code I've tried: For the Bullet (Prefab)

```
   using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveBullet : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 10.0F;
    public float damage = 10.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        transform.Translate (0, 0, speed);


    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){

        col.gameObject.BroadcastMessage("ApplyDamage", damage);



    }
}
```

And the one for the Enemy:

```
public class enemyhealth : MonoBehaviour {

  public int health = 100;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
  }
  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
  }

  void OnDamage(){
    health--;
    if (health <= 0) {
      Destroy(gameObject);
    }
  }
}
```

What's not clear to me as well is, what type of Collider I should use (Box Collider, CapsuleCollider...) Or doesn't it makes a difference?

As I understood, Rigidbody is used for an other "technique" to make damage, am I right?

Comment: pew pew, pew pew!

Comment: Would it not make sense to just declare a Healthbar monobehaviour that tracks the health of a game object its attached to? then yes you are correct you need to handle a collision with say weapons / projectiles and basically do what you are already doing.

Comment: isnt that almost the same what I am doing?

Comment: Every bullet does have the upper script on it and the enemy has to 2nd script attached. But when the bullet hits the enemy, the health doesn´t become less...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some reference : 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Check
Both objects (bullet and enemy) have a collider with 'Is Trigger' enabled plus
the bullet has a rigidbody.

You can use the collider you prefer.

I rewarote youre code this way:

```
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    transform.Translate (0, 0, speed);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Enemy){
    if(Enemy.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
    {
        Enemy.gameObject.SendMessage("OnDamage", damage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from reading your code is that you send a message passing a param (the damage amount) ...

```
gameObject.SendMessage("OnDamage", damage);
```

You then declare a method that takes no params to handle it ...

```
void OnDamage(){
```

My guess is that the unity compilation process is not creating a correlation between these 2 because of that mismatch.